# Immutable.js - why does calling map() on a Record mutate the original object?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Let's create an `Immutable.Record` and modify it with `map`:

```
let R = Immutable.Record({a:1,b:2});
let r = new R();
let q = r.map(i => i * 2);
```

I'd expect that `r` remains unmodified and `q` is `Record { a:2, b:4 }`. But the actual result is that `r` was mutated and `q` (the return value from `map()` is `undefined`.

Why was the immutable object mutated? What are the rules that determine when an object is mutated in-place and when a new instance is returned?

Comment: Issue #268: [Map mutates Records](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/268)

Comment: Oh, so it's actually a bug, not a weird feature. Thanks!